# How to plot javascript array into jqplot?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, graph, jqplot

I have an array in javascript which i derived from `json_encode` in `jqplot`. how to plot the array in jqplot.

The following code gets the values and put in the two textboxes making a javascript array. I need to plot the `newArray2JS` in `x-axis` and `newArrayJS` in `y-axis`

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function parseMe(){
    var json=document.getElementById('json_text').value;
    var obj=eval('('+json+')');
    document.createElement('u1');


    alert(obj);
    for(val in obj){
        alert(obj[val]);


        //alert(obj[val]);
        //}
        }}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <form>
        <input type='text' id='json_text1' value='<?php echo $newArrayJS; ?>' />
        <input type='text' id='json_text2' value='<?php echo $newArray2JS; ?>' />
        <input type='button' value='parse' onclick='parseMe();' />

        </form>
        <div id = 'chart1'></div>
```

I am new to `jqplot` and json.

How can i do this.

Comment: that is json_text1 in getElementById

Comment: i get mysql values from php and encode it using json_encode. 
this code
function parseMe(){
 var json1=document.getElementById('json_text1').value;
 var bmi=eval('('+json1+')');
 var json2=document.getElementById('json_text2').value;
 var bmiDate=eval('('+json2+')');
 
 document.createElement('u1');

Comment: that gives javascript array. i need to plot that in jqplot. how to do this?

Comment: Here is a working example of JQPlot : http://jsfiddle.net/BLfRe/24/. Just put your array as input parameter. More info here : http://www.jqplot.com/

Answer (score 1):

first of all if you want to use jqplot, you need jquery. if you have jquery inside your page, you dont need the "document.getElement..." stuff. use jquery and the [jquery-selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) there!

given that your input contains an array as a string you could json.parse that and give it to jqplot:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var yourOptions = {} // fill this with your options (see jqplot docs)
    , stringArray
    , yourArray;  // this is the array you want to be plotted, which is filled onclick
  $('input[type=button]').on('click', function() {
    // the array as a string
    stringArray = $('#json_text1').val();
    try {
      // parse your string to make it a js-array
      yourArray = JSON.parse(stringArray);
      // and now jqplot it (see more info on how to use this in the jqplot-docs: http://www.jqplot.com/docs
      $.jqplot('#chart1', yourArray, yourOptions);
    } catch (e) {
      // you should do something here if your string is not parsable
    }
  });

});
```

this way, you can remove your javascript-onclick-attributes from your html!

Comment: my question is im not being able to fill that yourOptions with the javascript array i got.

Comment: yourOptions is just the jqplot-options (formatting axis and so on). the "yourArray" is the array you want to be plotted. on button.click, this is done (read the val from the input field, json parse it, and give it to jqplot